# How to Install windows application and sql server express on MAC Operating Systems ?

Tags: sql-server, windows, visual-studio

I have Developed an Windows Application in visual Studio 2010 by integrating Sql Server Express using prerequisites   that works fine in all windows Operating System.But my application should also work  other than Windows Operating Systems like MAC,LINUX . We didn't tested other than Windows Operating system.so we have an doubt weather MAC and LINUX Supports Windows Application with Sql Express.

Comment: Run your app in a Windows VM for non Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

Anything that depends on windows GUI will nor work under Mac or Linux without a lot of advance preparation. If cross platform use is  your goal, you're probably starting with the wrong set of tools.

Comment: then what shall i do to run my application in all operating systems @ddyer

Comment: choose appropriate tools and rewrite it.  You sound pretty beginner-ish so it's probably beyond your current skill level.  To start, consider using a language with has it's own user interface and which is also available on all the desired platforms.  For example Java might do the trick for you; or adopt a cross-platform toolkit such as QT.  Or outsource the GUI to a browser and deploy your application as a client/server.  There are lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You do not. YOu goto a mirror and ask the person on the other side why he did not bother to check system requirements before choosing technologies.

.NET will in 2015 run on Mac and Linux (outside Mono, MS puts the whole stack offically on those platforms). But SQL Server - no. Sorry. Whoever choose that should learn to read system requirements. I you drop SQL Server (and allow alternatives) and can wait for .NET 5.0 - then yes, that is doable.

At the moment your only rel way to do that is via virtualization. WINE may work - not sure, but definitely not something I would support. Full windows virtualization will work but is similar to installing another OS.

If that was a professional development, someone obviously did not consider "knowing what I do" to be part of the job requirements. Always funny.

Answer (score 0):

1) Linux, Rewrite in C++, using KDE or GNOME for front-end, use something like MySQL for back-end

2) OSx, Rewrite in objective C, using MySQL for back end

3) Windows, Keep front-end but change back-end to MySQL

note MySQL used on all SQL servers to keep some of the development the same.

you could rewrite front end using something like Java so it will work on all platforms but i'm not a java developer so i'm not sure what is involved.

My best recommendation is that you find a different line of work as you don't seem to understand the first thing about development...